# Scrolling makes Gap in Staggered Gridview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

There is a Gap issue with my Staggered Gridview layout with scrolling. I am using pagination in this gridview. If i scroll continues up and down and then after i scrolls top a gap on there.

[image: image causing Gap]

Activity Code

```
staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
staggeredGridLayoutManager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
search_recyclear_view.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
```

ScrollListener

```
 search_recyclear_view.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(staggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                //for no gap use this
                ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager)search_recyclear_view.getLayoutManager()).invalidateSpanAssignments();
                // do something...
                getData();
        }
```

ImageAdapter

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            rlp.height = (int) (rlp.width * item.getImage_ratio());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(rlp);
            imageView.setHeightRatio(item.getImage_ratio());
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(baseuri + item.getImageName()).placeholder(PlaceHolderDrawableHelper.getBackgroundDrawable(position))
                    .into(imageView);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager sGrid = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
sGrid.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
```

try that.

Staggered grids are likely to have gaps at the edges of the layout. To avoid these gaps, StaggeredGridLayoutManager can offset spans independently or move items between spans. You can control this behavior via setGapStrategy(int).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: You really should explain your code, how it solves the problem.  Devil is in the details.